# How can I generate a series of maps from time series data in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, filter, mapping

I've got a polygon layer containing some time series data in cells and I'm trying to create a series of maps from it.

Data structure: every polygon has a timestamp and a value that I'm displaying on a map. There are usually multiple polygons "stacked" in one place with different timestamps.

What I'd like to do is to create one map for each unique timestamp using the same print layout, extent, layer styling, etc.

I tried using the Atlas feature of the layout manager by using the filter function with the expression `"date" = attribute(@atlas_feature, 'date')` and sort by `"date"`, but that didn't work.
The resulting pages all look exactly the same when I do this, but I don't understand why.

The only way I found that does exactly what I need is to use the filter function from the layer context menu in the layer overview. In there, I can use `"date" = '2012-01-01T00:00:00.000'` for example and then export the resulting map. I can't do that for all my layers by hand, though.

Any ideas how I could automate this approach?

Comment: How is the coverage layer setup? Do you have as many features in it as you have epochs (unique timestamps)? I'm not sure I understand how you built the atlas.

Comment: I've got multiple features per epoch. I'm trying to set up the atlas so it produces one page per epoch (and show only the features from that epoch).

Comment: Is a separate layer setup, with a polygon for each epoch, as the coverage layer?

Comment: No, it's all in one layer. A few thousand polygons in total and there's always a few of them sharing the exact same timestamp (that's what I call an epoch here)

Comment: I figured it out. Turns out you have to create a rule-based style schema, I adapted my approach from here: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8766
Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: But doesn't the atlas create as many pages as there are features in your coverage layer? And as far as I know, the atlas will always center its view on the features in the coverage layer, so you can't have the same extent for every page unless all polygons are identical (or their centroids at least). I'm still completely puzzled how you did your thing.

Comment: Sorry, I left that part out. Yes, I had way too many layers at this point. I just added another layer containing only the unique timestamps and used that as coverage layer instead.

Comment: So basically, the exact same case as with [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307954/qgis-3-variables-in-rule-based-rendering/311014#311014)

Comment: True! Wish I'd found that earlier :)